# Repeating same data across collections in Azure DocumentDB

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

When using DocumentDb for designing a conversation system, is it a good idea to repeat the conversation details for all the parties involved?

I have sharding implemented using the first alphabet of the user name. Now the user A sends a message to F, I and Z. Since these users are part of different collections (because of sharding) the message details are repeated in each collection. This design helps me with fast reading (it will be fast as I need to go to one location only to display the history). But writing could be tedious as I have to write to multiple locations.

So, my question is when building such systems using DocumentDb, can we repeat the details? Or is it a good idea to have a centralized collection for the details and maintaining that id part of each users collection?

Please help.

Thank you,
Soma.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are talking about is akin to the tradeoff between fully normalized and partially denormalized data modeling, although even that's not a perfect fit because of the different collection issue. That said, I think the answer given about denormalization holds in this case, "It depends."

You are thinking in the correct terms by pointing out that you make reads faster.

My advice however, is to not denormalize unless you have evidence from production that fully normalized is not fast enough and from experiments that denormalized is faster. Every denormalization increases the risk of data corruption and it's notoriously tricky to resolve bugs like this. Have you tried storing it in one place? Is that fast enough? Have you done an experiment that makes you think this denormalization is faster?

Also, I have the opposite instinct about performance in this case. If you have to issue two queries and they hit different collections as opposed to one, I would expect your throughput to go up and your latency for the combined pair of operations to go down, assuming you run them in parallel.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. At present we are still experimenting with various options. We will run some tests before settling on one idea.

Comment: That's not true about DRY being only for code -- it applies to data as well. To quote the canonical definition: "Every piece of knowledge must have a single, unambiguous, authoritative representation within a system." That said, there are times when copies of information are extremely useful (e.g. when caching) as long as the system knows to never treat a copy as if it were the original.

Comment: I just went back and skimmed my copy of Andy Hunt's Pragmatic Programmer and found the definition you give. They even give examples for database schemas, build systems, and configuration files, but I don't see any examples for data like what we're talking about here. That said, my "only code" comment was clearly too narrow and the answer to this question is not helped by clarifying the definition of DRY so I removed that from my answer.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you're partitioning on user, could this be a suitable case for partitioning on an Id by conversation instead? You could then keep track of conversations on the userId. Will require an extra call to get the conversation Id, but once you have it you should be all set.